# What are some good crawlers that can help download files

Tags: web, web-crawler

For one of my statistics project, I need to RANDOMLY download several files from a google patent page, and each file is a large zip file. The web link is the following:

http://www.google.com/googlebooks/uspto-patents-grants-text.html#2012

Specifically, I want to RANDOMLY select 5 years (The links on the top of the page) and download (i.e 5 files). DO you guys know if there's some good package out there that is good for this task?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just download all of the archives, save them on disk and then do your random thing? I don't know what programming language you're writing in, but in C# this can be done in about 20 lines of code (give or take).

Comment: That's true, but since it's a team project we would like to have some scripts that can select samples online and download ONLY the ones that are selected. All those files are fairly large so we would like to grab only the things we need in order to save some memory space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That page contains mostly zip files and looking at the HTML content it seems that it should be fairly easy to determine which links will yield a zip file by simply searching for a `*.zip` in a collection of candidate URLs, so here is what I would recommend:

```
fetch the page
parse the HTML
extract the anchor tags
for each anchor tag
    if href of anchor tag contaings "*.zip"
        add href to list of file links

while more files needed
    generate a random index i, such that i is between 0 and num links in list
    select i-th element from the links list
    fetch the zip file
    save the file to disk or load it in memory
```

If you don't want to get the same file twice, then just remove the URL from the list of links and that randomly select another index (until you have enough files or until you run out of links). I don't know what programming language your team codes in, but it shouldn't be very difficult to write a small program that does the above.